# How to add an About dialog before the settings in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio, about-box

Do you know how to create a menu about in the ActionBar and show a dialog?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all i recommend you to use google for your question.because you can find dozens of websites and questions about this issue.But since you are a starter i will try to give you an answer.

That three button thing on your action bar is for menu items.which you can add it with the following tutorials by google itself.

[MENUS](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

[HANDLING CLICK EVENTS](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html)

On its on click event you may want to use dialog window(which you can also google it and find) but here is the link for it.

[Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Here is one custom dialog example.

[Custom Dialog](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

with this links you may want to have this menu and dialogs if you just follow the instructions.

Comment: Sorry I am starter I really want to know about Android Studio App but it still difficult for me because I am not background in IT. Anyways, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I recommend for you to follow some tutorials and read developer page of android.if you liked my answer please accept it by clicking the tick at the left of my answer